# how to enforce equal width of several widgets based on their contents

Tags: c++, qt

I have run into a very interesting problem. I have several widgets (they are `QPushButton` but in general they can be any `QWidget`), they are placed into an arbitrary hierarchy of layouts in a window (i.e. they are not necessarily in the same layout). But I want them all to keep the same width which should correspond to the maximum width of any of them. The width is of course determined by their content, which in case of `QPushButton` is the text of the button).

I created this code:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QGridLayout>
#include <QPointer>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QVector>
#include <QWidget>

class WidthEqualizer : public QObject
{
public:
    explicit WidthEqualizer(QObject *parent = nullptr) :
        QObject(parent)
    {
    }

    void addWidget(QWidget *widget)
    {
        m_widgets.append(widget);
    }

    int widthHint() const
    {
        // A hack: Recursion protection should prevent endless recursion 
        // when calling size hint from WidthEqualizer for its widgets.
        m_recursionProtection = true;

        // We get the maximum width of size hint of all widgets.
        int width = 0;
        for (QWidget *widget : qAsConst(m_widgets))
        {
            if (widget != nullptr)
            {
                width = qMax(width, widget->sizeHint().width());
            }
        }
        m_recursionProtection = false;
        return width;
    }

    bool recursionProtection() const
    {
        return m_recursionProtection;
    }

private:
    QVector<QPointer<QWidget>> m_widgets;
    mutable bool m_recursionProtection = false;
};

class PushButton : public QPushButton
{
public:
    explicit PushButton(const QString &text = {}, QWidget *parent = nullptr) :
        QPushButton(text, parent)
    {
        setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Fixed, QSizePolicy::Fixed);
    }

    void setWidthEqualizer(WidthEqualizer* equalizer)
    {
        m_equalizer = equalizer;
        m_equalizer->addWidget(this);
    }

    QSize sizeHint() const
    {
        if (m_equalizer != nullptr && !m_equalizer->recursionProtection())
        {
            int width = m_equalizer->widthHint();
            int height = QPushButton::sizeHint().height();
            return QSize(width, height);
        }

        return QPushButton::sizeHint();
    }

private:
    QPointer<WidthEqualizer> m_equalizer;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QWidget window;
    auto equalizer1 = new WidthEqualizer(&window);
    auto equalizer2 = new WidthEqualizer(&window);
    auto layout = new QGridLayout();
    window.setLayout(layout);
    auto button1 = new PushButton("EQ1 very very very long");
    button1->setWidthEqualizer(equalizer1);
    layout->addWidget(button1, 0, 0);
    auto button2 = new PushButton("EQ2");
    button2->setWidthEqualizer(equalizer2);
    layout->addWidget(button2, 0, 1);
    auto button3 = new PushButton("EQ1");
    button3->setWidthEqualizer(equalizer1);
    layout->addWidget(button3, 1, 1);
    auto button4 = new PushButton("EQ2 long");
    button4->setWidthEqualizer(equalizer2);
    layout->addWidget(button4, 1, 0);
    window.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

It shows this situation:

[image]

This is exactly what I wanted to achieve. There are two groups of buttons "EQ1" and "EQ2". Note that the buttons in each group have equal width, which is given by the width of the button with the longer text. For demonstration purposes I put the buttons into a grid but this can be any possible hierarchy of layouts. And even if I change the text on any of them the correct widths will be maintained automatically.

My question is this: The code works but I find this code too complex for such a simple task. Does not Qt provide any simple trick to achieve the same without so much coding? Ideally make it even more general without the need to override the push button or any other type of widget which I want to equalize widths for? Maybe some trick with layouts? Or maybe some clever metaprogramming?

UPDATE:
Why I need this? I want my UI to be clean and elegant, for example to have a window/dialog which has equal width of buttons at the top and also at the bottom. See e.g.
[image]

It looks much better than if each button has a different width. Of course I cannot set the width to be fixed, because this would get broken when I applied translations.

Comment: I can't think of any reason to layout buttons or any widgets like this. Why would one restrict widget from occupying unused space? Nothing is aligned, space is wasted. I've never even come up to idea behind this layout without two paragraphs of text. Why do you need this?

Comment: I have multiple buttons in a certain window/dialog. Some of them are at the top of the window, some of them are at the bottom... And I found that the overall visual impression is much better if all these buttons have the same width. It looks much cleaner than if each of them has different width. I simply believe that software should no only be functional but also beautiful :) (note that the grid in my example is just and example to show how the code works, so it is ugly, but it is not the point)

Comment: I updated the question to show my use case.

Comment: I see. Ui on second picture looks realy nice. I dont think there are easy way to achieve this. I'd use fixed widths because it's simple: less code, less debug, less errors, kiss fullfilled, It will probably work, and if not I'd fix it by using specific width value for problematic language.